# Possible to persist HKQueryAnchor in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: objective-c, healthkit

So I'm a bit dismayed that Apple has replaced a transparent, easy-to-handle `NSUInteger` with an `HKQueryAnchor` but has not provided an easy way to persist that `HKQueryAnchor`. Has anyone found a good way to do this with `NSUserDefaults`? The only persistence method I have seen is an [archiver to a local file](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13942), but my app persists everything in `NSUserDefaults`, and I'd like to keep it that way if possible. Is there a reliable way to store an `HKQueryAnchor` this way?

Comment: yes, your class needs to conform `NSCoding` protocol then you can archive or unarchive it anytime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can convert it to `NSData` using `NSKeyedArchiver` and store that in the user defaults.

To store:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:anchor];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"AnchorData"];
```

To retrieve:

```
NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AnchorData"];
HKQueryAnchor *anchor = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Comment: probably you are aware of the `HKQueryAnchor` class basically does not conform the `NSCoding` protocol...

Comment: @holex so it seems to conform to NSSecureCoding. so can I actually archive as above and store in NSUserDefaults or does something about NSSecureCoding prohibit NSUserDefaults?

Comment: I am running into consistency issues with this method @dan have you seen anything like this? I am having things return old anchor or nil values. I am using the code you suggested and before query fires i ask for most recent value.

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 5

You can declare the anchor as a computed variable which decodes the Data that you store in `NSUserDefaults` using `NSKeyedUnarchiver`

```
@AppStorage("anchorKey") private var encodedAnchor: Data?
    private var myAnchor: HKQueryAnchor? {
        if let encodedAnchor {
            // Decode the data to get HKQueryAnchor
            if let decodedAnchor = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: HKQueryAnchor.self, from: encodedAnchor){
                return decodedAnchor
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

On your `HKAnchoredObjectQuery`, you can then encode the newAnchor which the closure provides using `NSKeyedArchiver` which stores it to your stored value using `NSUserDefaults`

```
if let newEncodedAnchor = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: newAnchor, requiringSecureCoding: true) {
          // Store the encoded anchor data in UserDefaults
          self.myAnchor = newEncodedAnchor
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is building off @allmightu 's answer, but without the SwiftUI `@AppStorage` requirement. I also packaged it into a nice get/set syntax, so this is pretty much invisible to any consumer of the variable.

```
    let anchorKey = "defaults-anchor-key"
    var anchor: HKQueryAnchor? {
        get {
            guard let anchorData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: anchorKey) else {
                return nil
            }
            return try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: HKQueryAnchor.self, from: anchorData)
        }
        set {
            guard let newValue = newValue else {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(nil, forKey: anchorKey)
                return
            }
            if let anchorData = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: newValue, requiringSecureCoding: true) {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(anchorData, forKey: anchorKey)
            }
        }
    }
```